# Duda sobre strlen C++ libro "El lenguaje de programación C++" aritmetica de apuntadores

Tags: c++, punteros

Básicamente estaba leyendo en ese libro la sección de aritmetica de apuntadores, /capítulo2/página 58 (al menos en mi versión en español)
La función que hace (usando aritmetica de apuntadores) para contar los caracteres es así:

```
int strlen(char* p)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*p++) i++;
    return i;
}
```

Ahora bien, creo haber entendido a que viene el * en *p++, en definitiva es porque en C++ al final de cada cadena de caracteres hay un "\0" y dicho "\0" evalua falso si se toma como condición. Entonces en definitiva tenes que *p++ (que es lo mismo que decir *(p++) ) toma "\0" cuando esta al final de la cadena lo que hace que salga del while

Pero no me doy cuenta porque strlen devuelve, correctamente, 4 (si es evaluado con "hola") con ese código cuando me parece que debería estar devolviendo 3...
Digo, si yo le paso "hola" entiendo que lo que pasa es:

```
i=0
"*p++"
ahora p apunta a "o"
i=1
"*p++"
ahora p apunta a "l"
i=2
"*p++"
ahora p apunta a "a"
i=3
ahora "*p++" evalua a falso y sale del bucle
return i;
3
```

¿Pero sale 4?
Y cuando puse un cout en el while para ver que estaba pasando me encuentro con esto

```
o letra
1
l letra
2
a letra
3
  letra
4
```

Es como si el "\0" del final por alguna razón estuviera evaluando true, no lo entiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El razonamiento es correcto. Solo te faltó tener en cuenta el funcionamiento del operador de [postincremento](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec).

La descripción de esta documentación es:

> Post-increment and post-decrement creates a copy of the object, increments or decrements the value of the object and returns the copy from before the increment or decrement.

En español quiere decir que los operadores `post` (que se encuentran luego de la variable) crean una copia del objeto, lo aumentan/decrementan y devuelven la copia de antes del incremento/decremento.

Si no queda claro, mira esta función, es una posible implementación del operador.

```
int postincremento(int &n){
    int copia = n;
    ++n; // Se incrementa la variable original
    return copia; // Se devuelve una copia
}
```

---

Para que quede más claro, a efectos prácticos, tu código equivalente a este:

```
int strlen(char* p)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*p) {
        p++;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Entonces el razonamiento es:

```
h letra
1
o letra
2
l letra
3
a letra
4
  letra
```

Por cierto, cuando tienes un puntero o una referencia como parámetro es recomendable que marques su tipo como constante siempre que el algoritmo no necesite modificar la información. Porque si intentas ejecutar llamar la función con una constante, el código no compilará.

Por ejemplo:

```
// Si no es constante
int strlen(char* str);

int main(){
    const char * cadena = "Hola";
    strlen(cadena); // Error, no puedes pasar un tipo constante directamente
}

// Si es constante
int strlen(const char* str);

int main(){
    const char * cadena = "Hola";
    char nombre[10];
    strlen(cadena); // No hay problema
    strlen(nombre); // Tampoco hay problema
}
```

Como puedes ver en el segundo caso ocurre una conversión implícita a `const char *`. Tanto que [los arreglos decaen en punteros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Array_to_pointer_conversion) y que un tipo [no constante se convierte a constante](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Qualification_conversions).

---

Cabe mencionar que hay diferentes códigos para contar los caracteres. Por ejemplo estas son algunas que se me ocurren:

```
int strlen(const char* p)
{
    const char* inicio = p;
    while (*p)
        p++;

    return p - inicio;
}

int strlen(const char* p)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (p[i])
        i++;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: MIL GRACIAS !!!! Ahora me quedo mucho más claro